# Type or Namespace IQueryable Could Not Be Found

Tags: entity-framework, edmx-designer

Recently I added ado.net `.edmx` to my ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework but there is an error in context.cs

```
[DbFunction("Entities", "Split_Str")]
public virtual IQueryable<Split_Str_Result> Split_Str(string list, string splitChar)
{
    var listParameter = list != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("list", list) :
            new ObjectParameter("list", typeof(string));

    var splitCharParameter = splitChar != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("splitChar", splitChar) :
            new ObjectParameter("splitChar", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Split_Str_Result>("[Entities].[Split_Str](@list, @splitChar)", listParameter, splitCharParameter);
}
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** is the error!?!? We cannot read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to **show us!**

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't, try adding `using System.Linq;`